# What does "당연한 말씀이네요" means?

Tags: translation, meaning, phrase-meaning

There's this dialogue that happen before it "이제부터 어머니께 칭찬받을 때는 나처럼 하도록 해.", and then he said "당연한 말씀이네요" 
I think its like a sarcasm or so.

Comment: Could you show me more the dialogue?

Comment: Please provide more context on this dialogue.

Comment: It can be translated into "Too right." or "Precisely." If it really is a sarcasm, it also may mean "Nah, whatever" or "You're the boss."

Answer (score 1):

It could be interpreted either way, depending on the context and/or the tone of the person who spoke first in the dialog:

1. (with sarcasm): "Yeah, whatever...", "Aren't you so smart!", etc
2. (w/o sarcasm): "You're so right! I haven't thought of it." or something to that effect

Answer (score 0):

당연한 말씀이시네요 means it is a natural thing to say.
You can't say 당연한 말씀이시네요 to 어머니. Because it looks rude and impolite
you can say 감사합니다, 별말씀을요 or 천만해요.

Answer (score -1):

(시)어머니한테 칭찬을 받았을때는 '당연한 말씀입니다' 라고 할수 없습니다. 
이때는 '별말씀을요' 또는 '감사합니다' 라고 합니다.

따라서 '당연한 말씀입니다' 라고 하라는 것은 장난(joke) 하는 말로 보입니다.